# Refactoring UI callbacks with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring

I just did a slideshow with jQuery and looking at the code of "Next Slide" and "previos slide" buttons, I realized that they were almost the same, except for a couple of functions that change.

I think this could be refactored to be more efficient, but Im not sure how.

Could someone show me how?

```
//UI Binding
$nextbutton.on("click", function(){

    //Blocking control
    if (slideshowBlocked) return;
    slideshowBlocked = true;

    //Get active slide
    var $active = $slides.filter(".active");
    //Get new Slied
    var $newSlide = $active.next(".slide");
    if (!$newSlide.length){
        $newSlide = $slides.first();
    }

    //Prepare new slide beneath the active
    $newSlide.css({
        "z-index": 5,
        "display": "block"
    });

    //Fade out the active
    $active.fadeOut(function(){
        //Update states and CSS properties
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        $newSlide.addClass("active").css( "z-index", 10);;

        //Unblock slideshow
        slideshowBlocked = false;
    });
});
$prevbutton.on("click", function(){

    //Blocking control
    if (slideshowBlocked) return;
    slideshowBlocked = true;

    //Get active slide
    var $active = $slides.filter(".active");
    //Get new Slied
    var $newSlide = $active.prev(".slide");
    if (!$newSlide.length){
        $newSlide = $slides.last();
    }

    //Prepare new slide beneath the active
    $newSlide.css({
        "z-index": 5,
        "display": "block"
    });

    //Fade out the active
    $active.fadeOut(function(){
        //Update states and CSS properties
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        $newSlide.addClass("active").css( "z-index", 10);;

        //Unblock slideshow
        slideshowBlocked = false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that, as you said, both functions are basically doing the same thing, you can use a factory function and just pass in the options you want. No need for logic based on strings - just use the appropriate function names.

```
function slide (direction, fallback) {
    return function () {
        //Blocking control
        if (slideshowBlocked) return;
        slideshowBlocked = true;

        //Get active slide
        var $active = $slides.filter(".active");

        //Get new slide
        var $newSlide = $active[direction](".slide");
        if (!$newSlide.length) {
            $newSlide = $slides[fallback]();
        }

        //Prepare new slide beneath the active
        $newSlide.css({
            "z-index": 5,
            "display": "block"
        });

        //Fade out the active
        $active.fadeOut(function(){
            //Update states and CSS properties
            $(this).removeClass("active");
            $newSlide.addClass("active").css( "z-index", 10);

            //Unblock slideshow
            slideshowBlocked = false;
        });
    }
}

$nextbutton.on('click', slide('next', 'first'));
$prevbutton.on('click', slide('prev', 'last'));
```

Comment: `$active['next'](".slide")` is the same as `$active.next(".slide")`?? I have never seen that o.O

Comment: Yes, [you can use either](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties).

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your DOM, I can't be more precise, but it's basically something like this:

Rather than use $nextbutton and $prevbutton, use a more generic trigger.  For example, if both are buttons or links, then trigger on that level of button or link.  For example, **if** your trigger is something like

```
<ul class="controls">
    <li><a class="prev">Previous</a></li>
    <li><a class="next">Next</a></li>
</ul>
```

then bind to `.controls a` instead of `.prev` and `.next`.

Then both can use the exact same code except for:

```
//Get new Slide
var $newSlide = $active.next(".slide");
if (!$newSlide.length){
    $newSlide = $slides.first();
}
```

Instead you'll have to do something like:

```
//Get new Slide
var isPrev = $(this).hasClass(theNameOfClassOnPrevControl);
var $newSlide = isPrev ? $active.prev(".slide") : $active.next(".slide");
if (!$newSlide.length){
    $newSlide = isPrev ? $slides.last() : $slides.first();
}
```

Hope that helps.  Let me know if anything needs clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant way but this at least calls one function instead of two.

```
var nextOrPrevious = function (nextOrPrevious) {
        if (slideshowBlocked) return;
        slideshowBlocked = true;

        //Get active slide
        var $active = $slides.filter(".active");
        //Get new Slied
        var $newSlide;
        if (nextOrPrevious === "next") {
            $newSlide = $active.next(".slide");
        } else if (nextOrPrevious === "previous") {
            $newSlide = $active.prev(".slide");
        } else {
            console.log("Wrong argument");
        }

        if (!$newSlide.length) {
            if (nextOrPrevious === "previous") {
                $newSlide = $slides.last();
            } else if (nextOrPrevious === "next") {
                $newSlide = $slides.next();
            }else {
            console.log("Wrong argument");
        }
        } 

        //Prepare new slide beneath the active
        $newSlide.css({
            "z-index": 5,
            "display": "block"
        });

        //Fade out the active
        $active.fadeOut(function () {
            //Update states and CSS properties
            $(this).removeClass("active");
            $newSlide.addClass("active").css("z-index", 10);;

            //Unblock slideshow
            slideshowBlocked = false;
        });
    };
$nextbutton.on("click", nextOrPrevious("next"));
$prevbutton.on("click", nextOrPrevious("previous"));
```